# Area under the line tangent to a curve at a point $(a, b)$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this question and It can simply be solved by using the formula of triangle, but the problem here we want to method of integration, is there is away to find the area of shaded area (Triangle) without using the formula of Triangle . any help appreciated. 
[image]

Comment: What's the function of the curve?

Comment: I think we should consider the curve in general as f(x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need the equation of the tangent line, whose slope is given by $m = f'(a)$, where $f'(a)$ is the derivative of the curve to which the line is tangent, evaluated at $x = a$.

Now, using the point $(a, b)$, the point of tangency, which happens to be a point on the line, to give us, along with slope, the equation of that line:

$$y - b = m(x-a) \iff y = mx + (b-ma)\iff y = m(x-a) + b$$

So we want the area under the line, evaluating the integral from $x = 0$ to the point where the line intersects the line $y = 0$, which is where $x = \dfrac{ma-b}{m} = a - \dfrac bm$

$$\int_0^{a - \large \frac bm} (m(x-a) +b)\,dx = \int_0^{a - \large\frac b{f'(a)}} \Big(f'(a)(x - a) + b\Big)\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

If $(a,b)$ belongs to the curve of a differentiable function $f(x)$, then one can find the equation of that line which connects the point $A$ and $B$ and then use the routine formula for that area:
 $$\text{Area}=\int_0^A ydx$$ where $ax+by=c$ is the formula of the connecting line.